# How to add a Price Rule programmatically in Magento2 backend?

Tags: magento2, backend, price-rules

I want to create a price rule, but instead of creating it from within the admin, I want to do it in either Setup/Patch/Data or do another way in backend. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see multiple examples of rule creation in integration tests data fixtures:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/SalesRule/_files